No c++ standard library found when compiling c++ code on Mac
I am learning how to run programs through the terminal on Mac, and I tried running one of my programs:
clang++ /.../file.cpp
clang++ -c /.../file.cpp

and each time I get an error telling me the compiler can't find the file in the standard library.
10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
    1 | #include <iostream>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~

The same error shows if I replace clang++ with g++, clang, and gcc.
After researching, I used cpp -v to find where my compiler/computer is looking. I downloaded clang directly from LLVM GitHub, and I then tried using --stdlib and --stdlib++-isystem to attempt to redirect the compiler's search, but each time I use it I get an error message
cpp --stdlib++-isystem <filepath of 'include' directory that contains library>
cc: error: no input files

I would guess that I'm doing things wrong, but I don't know what I don't know to fix the problem. Any help?

In general when using linux you should use a package manager to install apps. A package manager will install all dependencies automatically, so if you want to install a C++ compiler it will also install the C++ standard library for that compiler. On linux the standard package manager is called apt.

@john The last sentence is wrong. The standard package manager on Arch Linux is pacman, on RedHat yum/dnf, on SUSE zypper, on Alpine apk. apt doesn't exist for most Linux distributions.

@john -  Different linux distributions use different package managers.  Debian-based distributions (e.g. Ubuntu, Mint) mostly use apt.     Other distributions use different package managers - and can't necessarily even use apt.

@john jabaa is right, my Mac does not have apt installed.
I solved my problem by manually downloading clang/LLVM from github and replacing the newly downloaded 'include' file with the one that my computer was pointing to.

And frankly I'm not sure why this was closed as a duplicate, the linked post did not help at all.

@VladimirAndral Initially you said you were working with Linux, now you say that you are working on a Mac. These kind of details matter for this kind of question.

@VladimirAndral Anyway I've reopened the question since you are not working with Ubuntu (I had the same idea, I'm not sure why since you never mentioned it). So if you wish you can answer your own question with the details of what you did to solve your problem. Might help someone else in the future.

@john Apologies, I'm sure you guessed that I'm new to compilers and still learning terminologies. I'll be more aware of important details like the ones you mentioned.

The standard package manager for Mac is brew. Why is this question tagged with Linux? MacOS is not a Linux Distribution.

Answering my own question: After downloading clang/LLVM from its GitHub page (make sure the LLVM you download has your system's name), I replaced the include directory in the downloaded LLVM with the include directory that my computer looks to (listed in the cpp -v command).

Please don't ask follow-up questions in answers. Ask a new question.
